# Searching through table description in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

I am trying to search through a table and if the description contains a keyword , to have the "MIMSfield" row update.

See screenshot:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/jivnfus5r/full/]

Some direction would be awesome, not overly familiar with Access. Assuming this can be done with a VB module.

For example: If the description contains "Airlines" make the MIMSfield = A113

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Update the "MIMSfield" row to what?  You may be able to do this with an UPDATE query, but we need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use VBA.
In Access go to Tab Create, button Query Design, close the window with tables that appears, swich to SQL View and write SQL command like below (use your variables) and press Run(!)

```
UPDATE TableName SET MIMSfield = 'WhatEver' WHERE description LIKE '*KeyWord*';
```

You can make the query with outer parameters like this:

```
UPDATE TableName SET MIMSfield = [WhatEver] WHERE description LIKE '*' + [KeyWord] + '*';
```

You will be prompted to provide the parameters while running the query.

Comment: Now, What if I wanted to run multiple update statements at once?

Comment: To run more statements at once you need to put __;__ between them.

Comment: When I try to do this, it gives me an error "Characters found after end of SQL statement" .

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot the quotation mark after the '*KeyWord*, I have edited it in the answer

Comment: ( cc: @Sebastian ) Access does not support multiple statements in a single SQL string. You'll have to run separate UPDATE queries.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for wrong info. I expected it is supported. You can however use one query for multiple updates by using parameters in the query. I have edited the Answer to show how.

Comment: What if I wanted to only insert the MIMSfield once on any given CASEGUID ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make a table of codes for MIMSField with keywords i.e. A113 for Airlines, A104 for car etc. than use VBA module.